# Stop SMS reaching inbox in Android

Tags: android, sms

I need to filter SMS in Android such that SMS which matches my condition moves to my application inbox and the rest go to native inbox.

But I can't delete/stop SMS reaching native inbox since `abortBroadcast()` is supported only for default messaging application. So, how can I handle this without making my application as default message application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know google now assigns the largest possible integer for the default messaging app in the BroadcastReceiver's priority value. Therefore you can't catch the SMS before the default app to cancel it. (Thats what you have found)

The only method I see is to get the SMS in a lower level and delete it from the messages database using the from and to numbers and the timestamp.

Comment: That's fine.. Can i make the unread sms as read so that no notification will come for that sms?

Comment: notification is the problem. it is not in control in the course I mentioned. But you can certainly make the SMS read.